# What does the parameter *labels* and *env* in docker daemon.json do?

Tags: docker

What does the parameter `labels` *and* `env` in docker `daemon.json` do?

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3",
    "labels": "test",
    "env": "os,customer"
  }
}
```

After reading the docker documentation, there is no description for it. And I set it up, I didn't find anything that worked.

Is it **just a marker** for docker daemon?

Reference document：[dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)、[Docker object labels](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/)

---

Update by 01/12/2023:

According to your quote from the document, no additional fields were added to the log after my testing.

> If the logging driver supports it, this adds additional fields to the logging output. The following output is generated by the json-file logging driver.

So, I created a test container (hello-world), but I don't see any information about the `env` or `label` fields in it.

```
# docker run hello-world
# less /var/lib/docker/<Container_ID>/<Container_ID>-json.log
```

[image]

The only way that I found out about `env` *and* `labels` was to run `docker inpect`

```
# docker inspect <Container_ID>
```

[image]

So, they are just arbitrary labels.

Answer (score 0):

Just an arbitrary label you can set, a log driver might use to configure its behavior.

In this case:

> If the logging driver supports it, this adds additional fields to the logging output. The following output is generated by the json-file logging driver:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-logging-driver-for-a-container